# Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to use Qt as matplotlib backend. i have checked it both on kaggle and google colab, but problem is same.

When i write

```
%matplotlib qt5
```

i got following error

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

When i print default backend, its already Qt5Agg

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
```

Comment: I'm getting this in Jupyter Notebook launched from Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). On regular windows it works fine.

Comment: how did you solve this @TomNorway ?

Comment: @LeoGallucci Since qt5 works within the operating system / environment you are running in, and WSL doesn't by default show a user interface (just a terminal), I do not think you can use the qt5 backend within WSL. You will have to either use something like jupyter notebook in the browser or VScode.

Answer (score 10):

This is happening because Google Colab and Jupyter run on virtual environments which do not support GUI outputs as you cannot open new windows through a browser.

Running it locally on a code editor(Spyder, or even IDLE) ensures that it can open a new window for the GUI to initialize.

For coding the GUI it is best to do it locally on a full-fledged code editor.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential solution for this issue:
Install and run a Xvfb instance in your server. Then check the environment variable $DISPLAY set properly.
Try matplotlib use qt5 again.